# wmic query fails with "NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL - Buffer too small" error

Tags: windows, wmi, cacti

I have a class that creates an object in WMI and I'd like to query it from a linux machine running cacti using wmic.

If i run the query I get an error, see below:

`/bin/wmic --namespace='ROOT\CIMV2\mynamespace' --authentication-file=authfile //hostwithwmi "SELECT Column FROM MyClass WHERE key='myKey'"`

`[wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] ERROR: Retrieve result data.
NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL - Buffer too small`

Why that? If I do it on a windows machine (Get-WmiObject) it works, and the result is an integer (a number between 0-200).

Is there any way to bypass that?

Thank you very much.